# SQL Connection Pooling

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling

I have a .net website connecting to SQL. Just wondering if connection pooling is  enabled by default or is it something I have to activate myself?

Answer (score 10):

Essentially this is enabled by default when using the `System.Data.SqlClient` data provider. There is a very good article about the semantics which can be found here:

[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, you can view the `ConnectionString` property reference of the `SqlConnection` class here:

[SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

This contains a lot of information about the options that are available when configuring a connection string for Sql Server.

You should also note that the actual connection pool itself is kept within the `Application Pool` assigned to the website/web application, so be aware that if you have multiple sites/web applications using the same `Application Pool` they will also share the same connection pool which may not be desirable to you.

As such, I would recommend assigning a new application pool for each website and each web application underneath the site itself. You can find information about application pools at the link below:

[Application Pools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831797.aspx)